Firebase Notification Permission Error: "permission":"cloudmessaging.messages.create"
I'm encountering a permission error when calling the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) API for notifications. While the API retrieves details and generates a Firebase token successfully, the response includes the following error message:

Firebase API Call Response: {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Permission 'cloudmessaging.messages.create' denied on resource '//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/restaurant-b6abd' (or it may not exist).","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","details":
[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason":"IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED","domain":"cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com","metadata":{"resource":"projects/restaurant-b6abd","permission":"cloudmessaging.messages.create"}}]}}

I am using laravel 8 and called API from Android device

Go to Google Console > Go to "IAM & Admin" -> "Service Accounts". > "Firebase Admin" and select the "Firebase Admin: Send Messages" role.

Here are the permissions i have given
firebase-adminsdk - Firebase Admin - Adv sec insight,
Firebase Admin SDK Admin Service Agent - Adv sec insight,
Firebase App Check Admin - Adv sec insight,
Firebase Auth Admin - Adv sec insight,
Firebase Cloud Messaging Admin - Adv sec insight,
Firebase Grow Admin - Adv sec insight,
Firebase Remote Config Admin - Adv sec insight,
Firebase SDK Provisioning Service Agent - Adv sec insight,
Owner - 9362/9363 excess perms,
Service Account Token Creator - Adv sec insight,
